# restructuredtext include partial rst directives from other files (i.e. templates)

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm looking for a way to include partial rst directives from another file.

I have some restructured text files that have repeating table definitions, and I would like to make this a reusable template to avoid redefining the same table again and again.

multiple files list tables that all start like to following (i.e. common settings and header) but the actual data rows afterwards differ.

```
.. list-table::
    :align: left
    :header-rows: 1
    :width: 100%
    :widths: 25 25 25 25

    * - ColumnHeader1
      - ColumnHeader2
      - ColumnHeader3
      - ColumnHeader4
```

The include directive does not seem to work for this, as it will parse the line-table and then include the result, I cannot add additional rows to that line-table afterwards.

Is there any way that I could achieve this?

**EDIT**:
Forgot to mention that I use restructuredtext as part of sphinx. It seems it is quite easy to extend sphinx: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/development/tutorials/helloworld.html

**EDIT2**:
Moved my solution to an answer to this question

Comment: If you have a solution to the problem, post it as an Answer.

Comment: @mzjn I wasn't sure if it is okay to post an answer to my own question, I moved my "solution" to an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found  a way to implement this as a sphinx extension (following this tutorial https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/development/tutorials/helloworld.html)

```py
from docutils.parsers.rst.directives.tables import ListTable
from docutils.statemachine import ViewList


class MyTable(ListTable):
    def run(self):
        header_rows = ViewList([
          '* - ColumnHeader1',
          '  - ColumnHeader2',
          '  - ColumnHeader3',
          '  - ColumnHeader4',
        ])
        self.content = header_rows + self.content


        self.options['header-rows'] = 1
        self.options['width'] = '100%'
        self.options['widths'] = '25 25 25 25'
        self.options['align'] = 'left'
        return super().run()


def setup(app):
    app.add_directive('my-table', MyTable)

    return {
        'version': '0.1',
        'parallel_read_safe': True,
        'parallel_write_safe': True,
    }
```

This let's me define tables like this now:

```
.. my-table::

    * - Column 1
      - Column 2
      - Column 3
      - Column 4
```